# Why the input capacitance value decrease as the input voltage increases?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, inverter, cmos

Following is the screenshot of the logic [CMOS-inverter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hcu04.pdf?ts=1601864147334&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD74HCU04) curve (Input capacitance vs voltage).

Why the input capacitance decreases with the increase of input voltage?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sincw these input_capacitance spikes are occurring, in each case, at VDD/2 where typical CMOS inverter designs have Nchan and Pchan conductances tweaked via W/L to operate, I suspect these spikes are

- MILLER EFFECT capacitance multiplication

and the FET's gate_drain overlap capacitances are modulated by higher and higher voltages at the drain.

Answer (score 2):

A reverse-biased semiconductor diode's capacitance is a function of voltage. This effect is used in the [varactor or varicap diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap), a voltage-dependent capacitor. Wikipedia has an [illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Varactor_function.svg) of this, showing that increasing bias narrows the depletion zone, decreasing capacitance.

Answer (score 2):

The [<strike>Philips</strike> <strike>NXP</strike> Nexperia HC(T) User Guide](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/user-manual/HCT_USER_GUIDE.pdf) says:

> **7.6 Input capacitance**
>
> … is specified as
> 3.5 pF (typ.) and comprises package, bonding
> pad/interconnecting track, input protection diode and
> transistor gate capacitances. […]
> The initial decrease in capacitance as V<sub>I</sub> rises
> from zero or falls from 5 V is due to increased reverse bias
> on the protection diodes. The peak is caused by internal
> Miller feedback capacitance when the inverter is in its
> linear mode.

With a higher supply voltage, the drain-source voltage of the input MOSFETs increases, which decreases the input capacitance:

[image: capacitance vs. drain-source voltage]